# Minimum amount of days travel insurance policy should cover for Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, legal, insurance

My father in law is travelling to France, for 4 days, (01/07-04/07). Is there a minimum duration for which the travel insurance needed to apply for a Schengen visa must be valid? In other words, can his travel insurance cover just the duration of the trip, or should it last longer?

Comment: I re-phrased the question trying to clarify it. Please roll back my edits if you feel I distorted your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is taken up in Article 15 of [Regulation (EC) # 810/2009](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810) (otherwise known as the 'Schengen Visa Code'), which says...

> 3. The insurance shall be valid throughout the territory of the Member States and cover the entire period of the person’s intended
>      stay or transit. The minimum coverage shall be EUR 30 000.

and for the case of multiple entry Schengen visas...

> 2. Applicants for a uniform visa for more than two entries (multiple entries) shall prove that they are in possession of adequate and valid
>      travel medical insurance covering the period of their first intended
>      visit.

So any day (or partial day) that the applicant is in the zone, these paragraphs would apply.  To calculate the minimum coverage, add up the days between arrival and departure inclusive and you will meet the requirements of Article 15.

Answer (score 1):

I was told in Finland visa center that insurance should cover all days of the first trip. Maybe other Schengen countries have other rules